# python 2.X и unicode-строки

Tags: python, unicode

Перешел на 2.7 c 3.2 версии и теперь не получается элементарное в 3.2 действие: запись юникод-строки в файл.

Получаю из сети страницу и парсю ее lxml, получаю, например, строку:

```
u'+100500 - \xd0\x9b\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5 \xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8c\xd1\x8e'
```

При попытке записать эту строку в файл ворох ошибок (st - эта строка):

```
>>> open(r'c:\text.txt', 'w' ).write(st.encode('cp1251'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 10-18: c
haracter maps to <undefined>
```

Если игнорировать ошибки с .encode('cp1251', errors='ignore') то от строки остаются только пробелы и цифры.

Исходная строка в utf. 
Как записать строку в файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Засиделся видимо, исходная строка не была в утф, отсюда и весь сыр-бор. Стоило только спросить, как сам нашел ответ.